# Making a regex expression for adding single quotes in numbers comma seperated

Tags: regex

I have a list of numbers comma seperated. what is the regex pattern to add single quotes around them.

Have this-
1234434343243,43432,2323232,5342324324324

Want this-
'1234434343243','43432','2323232','5342324324324'

I am using notepad++ or msword not writting program.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find what:

```
(\d+)
```

Replace with:

```
'\1'
```